# Shorthand for  $0<i<1$ , $0<j<1$, $0<k<1$

Tags: article-writing

Is it good style to write $0<i<1$, $0<j<1$, $0<k<1$ as $0<i,j,k<1$?

The following does not seem so clear:

$0<i,j<1$

as it may be interpreted as:  $0<i $ and $ j<1$ or $0<i<1$, $0<j<1$

Comment: Yes, that’s fine.

Comment: In my opinion yes

Comment: I assume there is no order among $i$, $j$ and $k$.

Comment: Another option is $i,j,k \in ]0,1[$ (or $i,j,k \in (0,1)$) depending on how you prefer to write open intervals.

Comment: If there is danger of it being misunderstood, then you can state early on that when you write "$0\lt i,j\lt 1$" etc. you mean that *each* of $i$ and $j$ lies between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Don't be afraid of words in mathematical writing.  Example:  "$i$, $j$, and $k$ lie in the open interval $(0, 1)$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on context.

> Let $0\le a$, $b\le 0$ and $c = a - b$. Then $0\le c$.

You can use an interval instead: $i,j,k\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

It is okay. The comma indicates that there is no necessary relation between $i,j$ and $k$.

Answer (score 4):

I would definitely interpret $$0 < i,j < 1$$ as $$0 < i < 1 \text{ and } 0 < j < 1. \quad (*)$$  I would **not** interpret it as $$0 < i \text{ and } j < 1. \quad (**)$$  It is conventional, when writing a single inequality between a variable and a constant, to put the variable on the left, so if I meant (**), I would write
$$i > 0,\, j < 1.$$

Comment: I think you meant $j \lt 1$ (or maybe $1 \gt j$ to avoid confusion) in $(\ast\ast)$ and afterwards.

Comment: @t.b.: Fixed.  I thought something didn't seem quite right.